# I'm unable to get the size of a file to upload with nativescript

Tags: firebase, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I'm trying evaluate the mime-type and the size of a image uploaded using `nativescript-imagepicker`. However seems like the module itself can't do it. How can I apply constraits to the file I'm uploading? (Like `max size` or `just png or jpg`)

There's my code:

```
 const context = imagepicker.create({ mode: "single" });
    context
        .authorize()
        .then(() => {
            console.log('imagePicker.authorize...');
            return context.present();
        })
        .then((selection) => {
            if (!selection || !selection.forEach) {
                console.log('Error on selection empty or not array:', selection);
                return;
            }
            selection.forEach((selected) => {
                this.processPhoto(selected);
            });
        }).catch((err) => {
         .
         .
         .
```

Processing the image...

```
    processPhoto (selectedPhoto: any) {
    console.log('uploading photo to firebase', selectedPhoto);
    this.firebaseService.getImagePickerLocalFilePath(selectedPhoto)
        .then((localFilePath: string) => {
            console.log('about to upload file:', localFilePath);
            return this.firebaseService.uploadFile(localFilePath);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            this.isLoading = false;
            this.messageService.handleErrorRes(err);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to read the `size` & `extension` on [File](https://docs.nativescript.org/api-reference/classes/_file_system_.file) and prevent upload when they do not match your constraints.

```
const file = fileSystemModule.fromPath(localFilePath);
if (file.size <= YOUR_SIZE_LIMIT_IN_BYTES && file.extension.toLowerCase() === "png") {
    // Upload
} else {
   alert("File can't be uploaded");
}
```

Comment: For some reason this is returning 0 for file size, while the extension returns successfully. Ideas?

Comment: It works for me, make sure the file has data. If you still have issue, please share Playground sample.